# serialize and insert to mysql form with dynamic and static inputs php

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, serialization

I need to save form inputs that has static and dynamic tables using serialize jquery ajax call.

The form has two dynamic tables and two fields for receipt number and total amount. I need to call ajax with the save_deposit button. Need to save the data in mysql db as insert.

I tried to save one dynamic table via post with the php code in save php file. I want to do is to get this function done via ajax call.

```
{
<form id="myform" method="POST">
                <div class="panel panel-success">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4>Savings | Loans Deposits</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <label>Member</label>
                                <select name="member_id" id="member_id" class="form-control">
                                    <option value="">Select Member</option>
                                    <?php
                                    $query = "SELECT * FROM users_table ORDER BY id ASC";
                                    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
                                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                                    {
                                        echo '<option value="'.$row["id"].'">'.$row["username"].'</option>';
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                </select>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <hr>

                        <section id="savings">
                            <hr>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <INPUT class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Add Savings Payment" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <INPUT class="btn btn-danger" type="button" value="Delete Selected Payment" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <hr>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    <TABLE class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable">
                                        <TR>
                                            <TD><INPUT class="form-control col-md-2" type="checkbox" name="chk"/></TD>

                                            <TD>

                                                <select name="savings_account_number[]" id="savings_account_number" class="form-control">
                                                    <option value="">Select Member</option>
                                                    <?php
                                                    $query = "SELECT * FROM savings_account_table ORDER BY account_number ASC";
                                                    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
                                                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                                                    {
                                                        echo '<option value="'.$row["account_number"].'">'.$row["account_number"].'</option>';
                                                    }
                                                    ?>
                                                </select>
                                            </TD>

                                            <TD>

                                                <INPUT class="form-control text-right" type="text" name="savings_deposit_amount[]" onkeyup="total()" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)"/>

                                            </TD>

                                        </TR>
                                    </TABLE>
                                </div>


                            </div>
                            <hr>

                        </section>
                        <section id="loans">
                            <hr>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <INPUT class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Add Loans Payment" onclick="addRow('loans_table')" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <INPUT class="btn btn-danger" type="button" value="Delete Selected Payment" onclick="deleteRow('loans_table')" />
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <hr>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    <TABLE class="table table-bordered" id="loans_table" width="350px" border="1">
                                        <TR>
                                            <TD><INPUT class="form-control" type="checkbox" name="chk"/></TD>

                                            <TD>
                                                <label>Select Loans Account</label>
                                                <select name="loans_account_number[]" id="loans_account_number" class="form-control">
                                                    <option value="">Select Member</option>
                                                    <?php
                                                    $query = "SELECT * FROM savings_account_table ORDER BY account_number ASC";
                                                    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
                                                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                                                    {
                                                        echo '<option value="'.$row["account_number"].'">'.$row["account_number"].'</option>';
                                                    }
                                                    ?>
                                                </select>
                                            </TD>

                                            <TD>
                                                <label>Deposit Amount</label>
                                                <INPUT class="form-control text-right" type="text" name="loans_deposit_amount[]"/>

                                            </TD>

                                        </TR>
                                    </TABLE>
                                </div>


                            </div>
                            <hr>
                        </section>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <label>Receipt Number</label>
                                <input id="receipt_number" name="receipt_number" value="" class="form-control text-right"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <label>Total Amount</label>
                                <input disabled id="total_amount" name="total_amount" value="0.00" class="form-control text-right"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <label>Row Count</label>
                                <input type="hidden" id="row_count" name="row_count" class="form-control text-right"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <label>Save Deposit</label>
                                <button id="save_deposit" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save Deposit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
}
```

my insert to db is as follows, which is in the same php file

```
if (isset($_POST['receipt_number'])) {
    $user_id = $_SESSION['username'];
    $row_count = $_POST['row_count'];
    echo $row_count;
    $receipt_id = $_POST['receipt_number'];
    $savi_account_number = $_POST['savings_account_number'];
    $savi_deposit_amount = $_POST['savings_deposit_amount'];
    $member_id = $_POST['member_id'];
    $create_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    //check for remaining receipt id

    $check_item_id = "SELECT receipt_id from savings_transactions_table where receipt_id='$receipt_id' LIMIT 1"; //check if item exist
    $resultset = $conn->query($check_item_id);
    if ($resultset->num_rows == 0) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $_POST['row_count']; $i++) {
            $insert = "INSERT INTO `savings_transactions_table` (`id`, `receipt_id`, `sub_code`, `savings_account`, `user_id`, `amount`, `dr`, `cr`, `actual_balance`, `available_balance`, `created_user`, `created_date`)
VALUES (NULL, '$receipt_id', '1', '" . $_POST['savings_account_number'][$i] . "', '$member_id', '" . $_POST['savings_deposit_amount'][$i] . "', '0', '" . $_POST['savings_deposit_amount'][$i] . "', '0', '0', '$user_id', '$create_date')";
            $res = $conn->query($insert);

        }
        if ($res) {
            echo "<script>";
            echo "alert('Transactions Posted!')";
            echo "</script>";
        } else {
            if ($conn->error) {
                try {
                    throw new Exception("MySQL error $conn->error <br> Query:<br> $res", $conn->errno);
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    echo "Error No: " . $e->getCode() . " - " . $e->getMessage() . "<br >";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, so this is the form? Where's your code to insert the data into the database?

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](//stackoverflow.com/q/60174)

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: the code works, but what i need to do is to get the mysql insert part included in a separate php file and call via ajax. This is the help i need. Thanks for any help.

Comment: So what's your question? Do you want us to write it for you, or are you having trouble with implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add something like this at the end of your HTML:

```
(function($, window, undefined) {
    $('#myform').on('submit', function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.post(
            'ajax-insert-data.php',
            $('#myform').serialize()
        );
    });
})();
```

Also put your PHP code that handles POST into a different file named 'ajax-insert-data.php'

Comment: Thanks, I will try that out. Do i have to get the serialized content sanitized before assigning to, $receipt_id = $_POST['receipt_number'] as an example? Thanks

Comment: @dinesh You will receive data in $_POST in the same format as if you use standard POST without AJAX.